# Is 'you are required' an imperative?

Tags: imperatives

I've googled this but I cannot find an answer. The other similar threads asked was can the form of the verb 'be' be an imperative? I don't know if 'you are required' is a form of the 'be' verb.

> "You are required to ... do this and do that"

Comment: _Be good! Be careful!_ are imperatives. Your sentence may suggest a command, but the verb _are required_ is in the indicative mood, passive voice.

Comment: You need to distinguish between the general meaning of "imperative" and it's meaning with regard to English syntax.  If you are required to do something then it's imperative.  But that does not make it an imperative construction.

Answer (score 3):

*Imperatives* use the base form of the verb (including the verb *to be*) and issue commands or directives:

> - Come here!
> - Stop that!
> - Be quiet!
> - Be ready to leave at 6 o'clock.

*You are required to do this* does not have the grammatical form of an imperative. But it may be intended as a command by the speaker.

For example: *You are required to apply for a visa three months in advance of your journey* is simply conveying information.

*You are required to have your dog on a lead*, on the other hand, may be intended and interpreted as a directive:

> - Put your dog on a lead now!

This aspect of pragmatics is known as [Illocutionary Force](https://www.thoughtco.com/illocutionary-force-speech-1691147).